# Riddle to code, What am I saying?

Tags: riddle, cipher

> *The First provides me with gadgets.
>
>   The Second is seven doubled.
>
>   The Third is at the begin of endings.
>
>   The Fourth is difficult to differentiate in certain languages.
>
>   The Fifth is in the start of every sentence.
>
>   The Sixth is a question for lazy people.
>
>   The Seventh is not I but.
>
>   The Eighth is me.
>
>   The Ninth is what you will say when you figure it out.
>
>   The Tenth can also be before the first and sticks out its tongue.*

---

> My friend can't dance but he can do a 084973553.

What can my friend do?

Comment: Why am I the only person to have upvoted this? It's a great puzzle!

Comment: @randal'thor thx :D

Comment: This is delightful!

Comment: Your friend can't Sun, 10 Sep 1972 11:45:53?

Comment: @Chipperyman huh?

Comment: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*The First provides me with gadgets.*

> 1=**Q**: provides Bond with gadgets in the film series. **(From Zandar's answer)**

*The Second is seven doubled.*

> 2=**W**: double 7 => double U (see below) => W

*The Third is at the begin of endings.*

> 3=**E**: the first Letter (the begin) of the word ending is e

*The Fourth is difficult to differentiate in certain languages.*

> 4=**R**: In Chinese and Japanese there is no distinction between the letters l and r (It's a little more complicated than that but lets stick with that)

*The Fifth is in the start of every sentence.*

> 5=**T**: Every sentence in the code tag starts with T

*The Sixth is a question for lazy people.*

> 6=**Y**: lazy people ask "why" they have to do something.  **(From Zandar's answer)**

*The Seventh is not I but.*

> 7=**U**: Not I but You

*The Eighth is me.*

> 8=**I**: I am me

*The Ninth is what you will say when you figure it out.*

> 9=**O**: You will say Oh

*The Tenth can also be before the first and sticks out its tongue.*

> 10=0=**P**: As emoticon It sticks out the Tongue :-P. And 10=0 because it can also be before the first 0 < 1 **(Edited with using Zandar's answer)**

My friend can't dance but he can do a 084973553.

> So he can do a Pirouette

Comment: Nice answer! I've improved the formatting, with spoiler blocks and all - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Try to figure out 2 and 6, the answer on ten is not entirely correct.

Comment: No I don't mind thank you for that. ;-)

Comment: `The Tenth can also be before the first` I reckon this refers to how the answer for 10 is immediately before the answer for 1 in the you-know-what.

Answer (score 10):

Your friend can

> pirouette.

The solution to the riddle is:

The First provides me with gadgets.

> Q provides Bond with gadgets in the film series.

The Second is seven doubled.

> Z looks like two 7s put together.

The Third is at the begin of endings.

> E is the first letter of "endings".

The Fourth is difficult to differentiate in certain languages.

> R is the same sound as L in some languages, such as Japanese.

The Fifth is in the start of every sentence.

> T begins every sentence in this riddle.

The Sixth is a question for lazy people.

> Y - lazy people ask "why" they have to do something.

The Seventh is not I but.

> U - not I but "you".

The Eighth is me.

> I am me.

The Ninth is what you will say when you figure it out.

> O - when you figure something out, you say, "Oh."

The Tenth can also be before the first and sticks out its tongue.

> P looks like a mouth with a tongue sticking out, as in the emoticon :P. Being before the first indicates that this should correspond with 0.

Then the code is:

> Each number corresponds with the letter that is its answer (which happens to be that many letters into the first row of a QZERTY keyboard). Using this with the number 084973553 gives PIROUETTE.

Comment: Beat me to it by 1 minute. But I think 2 is N, the 14th letter.

Comment: Sebu was first, but you've done a more complete answer (also better formatted, until I edited Sebu's). +1

Comment: You have the second wrong, everything else is correct.

Comment: You have more correct than Sebu though, if you have the second correct I will accept this answer.

Comment: @knave Nope that's not correct

Comment: Thinking of the wrong keyboard, I guess! Edited.

Comment: The second is 7 doubled: The answer to 7 is "U" and doubled U is a double-u : W..... So it's a standard QWERTY Keyboard

Comment: still incorrect, Falco got it :)